# Запись звука с микрофона и обработка на лету

Tags: java, android

Создаю новый поток в котором происходит:

```
while (true) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            break;
        }
        final int size = mAudioRecord.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
        process(mBuffer, size); // операция обработки этого массива в этом же потоке (время обработки не измерял)
        //при этой долгой обработке, будет ли AudioRecord слушать и записывать данные в свой буфер?                   
    }
}
```

У меня звук записывается не полностью, рывками.

**process** записывает массив в файл, а так-же отправляет в модуль распознавания речи(внутри что то происходит в JNI). 
Не нужно ли тут выводить метод **process(mBuffer, size);**  в другой отдельный поток? Если да, то как это лучше сделать?

Я использую вот этот [класс](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/VoiceRecorder.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так:
Есть 3 потока, UI, Thread, Thread.

В первом Thread выполняется чтение данных и запись в **queue linkedlist**. А во втором потоке идет чтение из этого **queue linkedlist**.

**queue linkedlist** записываю mBuffer.clone().

чтение **queue linkedlist.poll()** считал и удалил